# Accessibility Insights for Windows flagging issues fixed in newer versions of .NET Framework

Tags: accessibility-insights

I am building an app that uses .NET Framework 4.5. One of the controls that I'm using is being flagged as an accessibility issue. That issue was fixed in .NET Framework 4.7.1, but I can't target a newer version now. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to update your .NET Framework but want to take advantage of the accessibility improvements in the later versions, you can use [Accessibility Switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility#accessibility-switches) to "configure your app to opt into accessibility features if it targets .NET Framework 4.7 or an earlier version but is running on .NET Framework 4.7.1 or later."